# When I use kuernets to execute kubectl create -f redis-master-controller.yaml

Tags: kubernetes

When I use kuernets to execute kubectl create -f redis-master-controller.yaml,I have an error:

```
kube-controller-manager: E0629 11:20:22.499930   28856 leaderelection.go:263] Failed to update lock: Operation cannot be fulfilled on endpoints "kube-scheduler": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

Comment: it looks like a cluster setup issue. Can you describe your setup?

Comment: Can you post the content of redis-master-controller.yaml?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `kubectl apply -f redis-master-controller.yaml` instead of create.